# How can I access parsed XML data and use it in other methods?

Tags: objective-c, xml, nsxmlparser

I have an XML file with a comment that has an ID on the bottom of my file that I am successfully NSLog"ing" out to the console. I used a NSXMLParser to find the comment via the foundComment method.  I then have a GetUID method at the bottom that I want to return my uid string.  I am not sure how to access my parsed data and use it in another separate method.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

XML FILE:

```
<audioTracks>0</audioTracks>
<!--7934fad5a3a -->
```

XMLParser.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyXmlParserDelegate : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate>

@end
```

XMLParser.mm

```
#import "XMLParser.h"

@implementation MyXmlParserDelegate

- (void) parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
foundComment:(NSString *)uid{

NSLog(@"UID: %@", uid);

}

- (void) parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {

}

@end
```

MAIN.mm

```
-(NSString *)GetUID {

        NSString * uid = nil;

        NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:MyData];

        MyXmlParserDelegate *parserDelegate = [[MyXmlParserDelegate alloc] init];
        [parser setDelegate:parserDelegate];


        [parser parse];

    return uid;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best answer depends on how reusable you need the parser delegate to be.

If the MAIN object is the only customer, then you can eliminate the delegate class altogether, just make `self` the delegate where you allocate the parser in `GetUID`.

A more general idea is keep your delegate class, and think of it specifically as a "uid finder".  In this form, it would contain a public `uid` property which it would initialize during the parse.  e.g.

```
// in the delegate
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundComment:(NSString *)uid {
    NSLog(@"UID: %@", uid);
    self.uid = uid;
}

// in the customer
MyXmlParserDelegate *parserDelegate = [[MyXmlParserDelegate alloc] init];
parser.delegate = parserDelegate;
[parser parse];
```

**EDIT**

```
return parserDelegate.uid;
```

We could get more general still, but the right approach will depend more on the nature of your model and degree to which the XML parsing process needs generalization.

Side notes:  It's customary to name classes and source files the same, so the `MyXmlParserDelegate` implementation file is better named "MyXmlParserDelegate.m".  Also, unless your implementations contain C++, they should have the ".m" extensions.

Comment: I tried to do what you said but on the line return parse.uid it throws an error saying "Property on uid not found on object type NSXMLParser"

Comment: I am sorry I am very new to objective-C.  I feel like it shouldn't be this difficult to call string from another method.  The error is still causing a stump for me.

Comment: It's me who should be sorry.  My suggested code contained an error.  See edit.  The parse delegate contains the new property, not the parser.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I am very new to objective-C.  Now that I see what you did it makes much more sense to use a self delegate